# $watch not trigger without $scope.digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I'm coding my own directive which is a dictionary :

`<div ng-controller="formController">
    <dictionary
               label="Editable"
               model="bso.dictionnaryObject"
               required=true
               dictionary-object="dico">
               </dictionary>
      </div>`

The "dico" value is set from a GET Call in a controller so it's mean it's not initialize as the time the directives is initialize

So i put a watch on my directive

```
 angular.module('dictionary', []).directive('myCustomer', function() {
return {
 templateUrl:  "dictionary.html",
    restrict: = "E",
    require: "^form",
    scope : {
        model: "=",
        dictionaryObject: "=",
        label: "@",
        editable: "@",
    },
    link : function() {
      $scope.$watch("dictionaryObject", function(newVal, oldVal){
                console.log(oldVal);
                console.log(newVal);
            }, true);
}};});
```

and from the rootScope :

```
app.controller('formController', function ($scope) {

 $.get("http://framework:8787/Services/dictionary",
        function (data) {
            $scope.dico = data;
            $scope.$digest();
        });}
```

So adding the $scope.$digest is the only way i found to trigger my watch.
Is there any way to not call $scope.digest() and triggering my watch ?

thanks

Comment: You should manually `$apply` your `$scope` changes, while you don't use angular services like `$http`, which already can to do it.

Comment: if you use jquery or any other javascript you need to manually digest \ apply the changes, as angular loses the track of code outside of angular cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This not working because `$.get()` don't knows that should be execute the digest cycle.
You should be use the angular way for this:

```
$http.get("http://framework:8787/Services/ofo/rest/dictionary/OrganisationStatusAvailabilityCode",
        function (data) {
            $scope.dico = data;
            //$scope.$digest(); If you use $http, the digest it's implicit
        });}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching me that and the really quick answer!